# Prestashop 1.5 can't enable SSL

Tags: ssl, https, prestashop, lets-encrypt, prestashop-1.5

I have strange problem. I have enabled SSL in my provider settings. I am using Let's encrypt certificate. But I cannot enable https in prestashop backoffice. If I check Enable SSL button to Yes and click save, following error shows up:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property: Validate::$values in /home/www/vozikyprozivot.cz/www/vozikyprozivot.cz/classes/controller/AdminController.php:1026 Stack trace: #0 /home/www/vozikyprozivot.cz/www/vozikyprozivot.cz/classes/controller/AdminController.php(581): AdminControllerCore->processUpdateOptions() #1 /home/www/vozikyprozivot.cz/www/vozikyprozivot.cz/classes/controller/Controller.php(158): AdminControllerCore->postProcess() #2 /home/www/vozikyprozivot.cz/www/vozikyprozivot.cz/classes/Dispatcher.php(348): ControllerCore->run() #3 /home/www/vozikyprozivot.cz/www/vozikyprozivot.cz/admin16/index.php(53): DispatcherCore->dispatch() #4 {main} thrown in /home/www/vozikyprozivot.cz/www/vozikyprozivot.cz/classes/controller/AdminController.php on line 1026

I tried to force enable redirect http to https in .htaccess file, but with no luck.

Can you help please?

Thanks a lot.

Eduard

Comment: What PHP version are you running and were there any core file modifications? Also in Prestashop 1.5, SSL works only on checkout.

Answer (score 0):

> Web Hosting company should mix something to your php

*Like this at settings.inc.php*

```
if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) ) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
    $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;
}
```

Comment: I don't follow. I have added this code to settings.inc.php, but problem remains the same.

Comment: Then ask Web Hosting provider. they should add it to the server to allow you to have SSL to prestashop.. Prestashop requires some extra php features to get to work. Good Luck

Comment: I asked provider to review all ssl settings and they told me everything is ok. So I presume that the problem is in prestashop.

Comment: Why dont u ad prestashop 1.6 or more? they have fixed the bugs

Comment: I am going to make new shop on different platform next month, but now google is showing warning that site is not secured and I am loosing customers.

Comment: Why dont you updrage presatashop directly from admin without loose data and affect customers... +